# c# save overwrite image error

Tags: c#, save, gdi+, overwrite

Im trying to save a file that i am using im getting a GDI+ error because im trying to save over the source file im using. Any solutions?

Example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap("images/sourceImage.jpg");
   sourceImage = CropBitmap(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, 50);
   sourceImage.Save("images/sourceImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}

public Bitmap CropBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int cropX, int cropY, int cropWidth, int cropHeight)
{
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(cropX, cropY, cropWidth, cropHeight);
    Bitmap cropped = bitmap.Clone(rect, bitmap.PixelFormat);
    return cropped;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the documentation for this constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Specifically the section that reads:

> The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed.

You must dispose the `sourceImage` before saving a new one. So, use different variables:

```
var sourceImage = new Bitmap("images/sourceImage.jpg");
var croppedImage = CropBitmap(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, 50);
sourceImage.Dispose();
croppedImage.Save("images/sourceImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
croppedImage.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you replace `sourceImage` with the reference from `CropBitmap`, the original file is still open. You will have to `Dispose` of it after reading it from the file, open a new `Bitmap` and save it overwriting the existing one.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap sourceImage = new Bitmap("images/sourceImage.jpg");
    Bitmap targetImage = CropBitmap(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.Width, 50);
    sourceImage.Dispose();
    targetImage.Save("images/sourceImage.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

[MSDN Bitmap documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0cbhe98f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The file remains locked until the Bitmap is disposed.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as when I dispose sourceImage it also applies to targetImage as it's still pointing to the same reference. Surely, I would need to somehow create a new instance of the image? How would I do that?